# How to run docker build command inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

This is related to working with CI/CD, I have a image in my private repo say **my_image**, when we trigger the pipeline gitlab-runner (shared) will pickup the image and run our ci commands on top of that.

My requirement is I need to have docker inside the image, so that output of some command "say build " will return a valid docker file and I need to build image on top of that file, using docker build

I am wondering is there any way to achieve this?.

Some context :

- I won't be having root access to the environment on which the runner is executing the job.
- Same is the case for the docker socket (no super user role will be given)

Thanks for any help..

I tried this with installing docker inside the container, docker -v command is working but no other docker command is working and they are failing saying (**Cannot connect to docker daemon, is the daemon running?**)

I don't think I can use priviliged containers accounting to the various security concerns.

I cannot mount docker binaries while running the image, since the job is being executed by the runner ( I think so, if I am wrong point it out..)

Comment: You need access to some Docker daemon.  If you can't access the host's Docker socket (which is reasonable from a security perspective) then you won't be able to build images.

Comment: After reading through a lot of posts ( I mean a lot....), I believe you are right. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yoi have to write a basic docker file like the following:

```
FROM <MY-BASE-IMAGE>

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz | tar xvz -C /tmp/ && mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/bin/docker
```

Then, when you run your container image, use the `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` argument to allow the embedded docker client to run by the host docker daemon.

Comment: I don't think I can run the container image ( correct me If I'm wrong ). As I mentioned the docker image will be picked up by gitlab-runner. I could not find any way to override the behavior of gitlab-runner while pulling and using the image.